# Arctan(f(x)) is almost the same as Erf(f(x)) for many f(x). Is the just coincidence or is there a reason?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, error-function

For example:

Arctan(x) is almost Erf(x) (subtle differences in absolute value and curve)

Arctan(x^50) is almost Erf(x^50) (difference in absolute value)

and many others, so we can conclude:

Arctan(f(x)) ~ Erf(f(x)) (~ meaning Is a poor approximation of)

Is there a reason for this or is this just a strange coincidence for the 10 equasion I tested (I listed only a few)?

Comment: This is not correct. Look at $\arctan x / erf(x)$ and check if this is approximately constant, and for which $x$.

Comment: This just goes to show that looking at a graph of two curves, or looking at specific cases, should not suggest approximate similarity in ways that are mathematically important.  The reason why $x^{50}$ seems to match well is because for $|x| < 1$, the main contribution to the value of the two functions is contained first few terms of the series expansions.  But for large $x$, the ratio $\tan^{-1} x / \operatorname{Erf}(x) \to \pi/2$.

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\arctan x}{\text{erf }x}=\dfrac\pi2$.

Comment: I just noticed that erf and atan, look similar. The logistic function is also similar. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function). Clearly these functions are not the same, but that are qualitatively similar. I'm glad you posted this, because I had the same observation.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think this is an accurate observation. Note that $$\text{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}$$ and $$\arctan(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ 
While there are some similarities between the Taylor Series of the two functions in question, I do not think it is enough to claim they are almost the same.

Comment: Ok, it just looked as if there was some kind of a connection, and there kinda is now that I see the Taylor series of them. I was able to come up with this: (arctan(x)*2/(sqrt(pi)))-(atan(x)^3)/4.9 . It is fairly close to erf(x). Though they aren't equal, they are close.

Comment: For sure. You can definitely find values of $x$ where the two are are equal or close to equal. I just wanted to show it is not always the case. Can I ask why you are interested in the relationship between the two?

Comment: Its mostly curiosity. We just got done covering Taylor Series in Calc II and when we discussed the Error function I noticed it look like arctan(x), and I wondered if there was some kind of a relationship between the two functions, and as it turns out they only differ by 2/(sqrt(pi)) and a n!. I suppose I am curious to see if erf(x) can be approximated use arctan(x) and other math functions.

Comment: Very cool, Taylor Series were my absolute favorite portion of calc II. I got to work with them again in Real Analysis which was great as well. Have you derived Euler's identity using a Taylor Series argument? For me that is the easiest/coolest way to prove that identity.

Comment: Yea it was a homework EC problem. When I saw that e^i(pi) = -1 the expression on my face was: =O. It really surprised me that cos and sin relate to e.

Answer (score 4):

It is for sure that one needs to scale $\arctan(x)$ for comparison. It is very likely to exist intrinsic relationships we have not found enough. But here seems one of them
$$\arctan(x)=\sqrt{\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\text{erf}(xt)\;dt$$
References can be found here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03310.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to consider the argument $f(x)$ rather than $x$.

What you call "almost the same" is in reality "they are both S-shaped curves with horizontal asymptotes" and the resemblance stops here. In practice, they are very different, in particular in the way they rejoin the asymptotes. There are million S-shaped curves with horizontal asymptotes.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=erf%28x%29%3Barctan%28x%29

Sorry to say, but your intuition is pretty naive and would be like claiming that $\pi e\approx\sqrt{73}$ is an interesting relation.

---

Regarding the case $x^{50}$, I guess that you just looked at small values of $x$ ($|x|<1$), so that $x^{50}$ is tiny and observed that *any* smooth function with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$ is well approximated by $f(x)\approx x$. Take $x=2$, and the dream vanishes.